# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre COUNT(*), COUNT(1) y COUNT(columna)?

Tags: sql, buenas-prácticas

Siempre me he preguntado cuál es la diferencia entre estas tres formas de usar `COUNT` en SQL (tampoco sé si hay diferencia según el manejador de base de datos que se esté usando).

Por ejemplo en MySQL, si tengo una tabla con 100 registros y hago esto:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(1), COUNT(columna) FROM tabla;
```

Me arroja tres columnas con un conteo correcto.

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre estas tres formas de usar `COUNT`?

¿Hay alguna de ellas, basándonos en pruebas objetivas, que sea más recomendada o da igual usar cualquiera de las formas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

En cuanto a resultados:

No hay diferencia entre `count(*)` y `count(1)`, por cada fila devuelta contará 1 igualmente.

Pero `count(columna)` es diferente: no contará las filas donde esa columna sea `NULL`.

Además, en este último caso puedes contar sólo los distintos:

```
select count(distinct column_b)
from table;
```

En cuanto a rendimiento, es complicado decir si uno es mejor que otro, ya que depende de si se usa sólo o con más campos y del gestor de base de datos:

`count(*)` en Oracle y PostgreSQL (posiblemente en otras también, pero no puedo afirmarlo) se detecta como una operación "trivial", se sabe que los valores son irrelevantes, así que usando el índice de la tabla puede obtener el valor sin realmente tener que recorrer las filas. Con count(1) el comportamiento es similar (el resultado por cada fila es una constante que no es null), por lo que tampoco hace falta obtener los datos para saber si hay valores NULL que descartar.

Comment: En principio,`count(1)` debe ser mas eficiente, ya que no accede a ningun valor de la tabla, simplemente devuelve un `1` por cada fila que exista.

Comment: count(*) tampoco accede, simplemente mira los índices para saber cuantas columnas hay

Comment: De hecho estoy mirando y parece que no hay diferencia de rendimiento, o eso se explica en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1221649). Aunque en [esta otra página](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/count.php) se dice que si :)

Comment: Parece que no hay consenso, así que modifico la respuesta acorde a lo encontrado

Comment: ah, la última vez que miré (porque yo usé `count(1)` y otro dev me sugirió usar `count(*) en un review`) encontré que `count(1)` era menos eficiente (porque tenía que mirar en cada operación que 1 no fuera null), mientras que `count(*)` estaba optimizado para nunca chequear el contenido de `count`. Después encontré [esto](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/11471.1027875769%40sss.pgh.pa.us) y a eso le creo más

Answer (score 4):

`COUNT(*)` cuenta los registros de la `SELECT` guardando en memoria las columnas de las consultas, es decir si en la consulta tienes 20 columnas y 300 registros, el guardara los 6000 espacios en memoria con su data. lo cual demoraria el procesamiento de la consulta.

`COUNT(columna)` cuenta los registros en los cuales "columna" no es NULL

`COUNT(n)` (donde ***n*** es un numero) toma el valor ***n*** (en este caso) como una tabla de unica columna donde su valor por cada registro es ***n*** para cada registro, no importando que sea de 20 columnas. para el ejemplo del primer caso, serian solo 300 * 1 = 300 valores, lo cual procesaría más rápidamente la consulta.

[Ver Ref Toad World](https://community.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/b/weblog/archive/2015/12/15/la-diferencia-entre-count-1-y-count)

Answer (score 0):

**`COUNT(*)`**  cuenta los registros de la SELECT.

**`COUNT(columna)`** cuenta los registros en los cuales "columna" no es NULL (columna IS NOT NULL)

**`COUNT(1)`** (con un numero) jamas la he utilizado.
La ayuda de Microsoft no la considera ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms175997%28v=sql.120%29.aspx))

Comment: `COUNT(1)` no se considera en la documentación que enlazas, pero es perfectamente válida.

Answer (score 0):

1. `count(1)` = cuenta todas las filas de la tabla.
2. `count(*)` = cuenta todas las filas de la tabla, además, carga toda la estructura de las columnas que componen la tabla, esto degrada la performance de la base de datos y futuros procesos.
3. `count(columna)`, cuenta los registros de la tabla asociada a la columna indicada, además de no considerar los valores nulos para la columna mencionada.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(1), COUNT(columna) FROM tabla
```

El **COUNT(*)** cuenta todas las filas de la tabla (mayor gasto de recursos)

El **COUNT(1)** es el entero 1 por cada fila resultado, esta se utiliza para hacer un sum (ej :select sum(count(1)) from tabla;). No la recomiendo

El **COUNT(columna)** cuenta todas las filas resultantes (cuando no es nulo)

Mi recomendación es realizar un **count(ID)** porque es Primary Key (nunca será nula) además de ser una columna indexada: el resultado es el más óptimo/rápido